# Azure pipeline runtime replace expression

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two identical `replace` statements in the azure pipeline yaml file

```
 - script: echo ${{ replace('refs/heads/origin', 'refs/heads', 'origin') }}
 - script: echo $[ replace('refs/heads/origin', 'refs/heads', 'origin') ]
```

except for one is a runtime expression while the other one is a compile time expression.

While the compile time expression works fine run time expression is giving me following error

```
line 1: replace('refs/heads/origin', 'refs/heads', 'origin') : syntax error in expression (error token is "('refs/heads/origin', 'refs/heads', 'origin') ")
```

How do I make runtime replace expression works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a variable for this:

```
variables:
  runtimeTest: $[ replace('refs/heads/origin', 'refs/heads', 'origin') ]
```

Then you can reference it in the `script` part with no errors:

```
steps:
- script: echo $(runtimeTest)
```

Comment: Cool, it works with hardcoded values, thank you.
Can you tell how can I do with PredefiinedVariables
`$[replace(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads', 'origin')]` returns refs/heads/master

Comment: It should work with the syntax you use. Note that according to the docs for `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` : "This variable is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy. This variable is only available in a YAML pipeline if the PR is affected by a branch policy." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services

Comment: So are runtime expressions supported only in variables? I need to call the format() function with a runtime variable and a compile time variable (from the `each` loop); is there no way to do that?

Comment: @Palec it's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. It would be great if you shape it into a separate question.

Comment: @Palec did you ever find a solution to doing this inside a loop? I've hit the same situation.

Comment: IIRC, I gave up and used a script for that, @Keab42.